# Dynamic pop-up having same id

Tags: javascript, popup, yui3

I am trying to dynamically create pop-ups without having the same ids for each one. The problems is, when the page loads, the first pop-up you select its id becomes the id for the next ones. Im not sure how to code it efficiently without this happening.

My code is:

```
// Display relative pop-ups to which link is clicked containing information about the field.
Y.delegate('click', function openPopUpInfo(e) {
    var panel,
    link = e.target.get('id'),
        content = Y.one('#' + link + 'Info');

    content.setStyle('display', 'block');
    panel = new Y.Panel({
        id: 'popUpPanel',
        centered: true,
        modal: true,
        visible: false,
        constrain: true,
        render: true,
        zIndex: 100,
        bodyContent: content,
        width: 350,
        height: 250,
        close: true,
        plugins: [Y.Plugin.WidgetAnim, Y.Plugin.OverlayKeepaligned],
        buttons: [{
            value: '',
            section: Y.WidgetStdMod.HEADER,
            action: function (e) {
                e.halt();
                panel.hide();
            }
        }]
    });

    panel.show();
}, '#interestfreetab', '.infoLink');
```

Answer (score 1):

What about just a simple counter??

```
var count = 0;
//existing code
id: 'popUpPanel' + count
//existing code
count++;
```

Answer (score 0):

set a global variable initially like

```
numberOfPopUps=0;
```

then, when you are making a new panel, when the id is declared, change

```
panel = new Y.Panel({ id: 'popUpPanel',
```

to

```
panel = new Y.Panel({ id: 'popUpPanel'+numberOfPopups,
```

then after the declaration increment

```
numberOfPopUps++;
```

Comment: That seems like a good idea but the id of the first pop-up is still given to the next one. Is it better to destroy the pop-up and create a new one?

Comment: Its creating the pop-up ontop of the other one. How can I destroy the one before that?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know what plugin or library you are using to create the popup, since I don't think thats native JS. What are you using? Perhaps its documentation explains how to destroy the popup? In JS you can destroy a variable with

delete varName;